# npm dns package error - C2039: 'Handle': is not a member of 'v8' (compiling source file ..\src\bufferutil.cc)

Tags: node.js, npm, dns, npm-install

I need to install [dns package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dns) to node_modules but if I run npm install dns I am getting this error. It seems some dependencies are not compatible with new node or npm versions. But what can I do with it? I dont want to downgrade.

```
 c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(107): error C2039: 'Handle': is
not a member of 'v8' (compiling source file ..\src\bufferutil.cc) [c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node _modules\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
  c:\users\vladi\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.18.3\include\node\v8-platform.h(16): note: see declaration of 'v8' (compiling source file ..\src\bufferutil.cc)
c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(107): error C2061: syntax error:  identifier 'Handle' (compiling source file ..\src\bufferutil.cc) [c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node _modules\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(109): error C2065: 'def': undecl ared identifier (compiling source file ..\src\bufferutil.cc) [c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modu les\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(111): error C2065: 'opt': undecl ared identifier (compiling source file ..\src\bufferutil.cc) [c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modu les\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(112): error C2065: 'opt': undecl ared identifier (compiling source file ..\src\bufferutil.cc) [c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modu les\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(115): error C2065: 'opt': undecl ared identifier (compiling source file ..\src\bufferutil.cc) [c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modu les\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(116): error C2065: 'opt': undecl ared identifier (compiling source file ..\src\bufferutil.cc) [c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modu les\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(122): error C2039: 'Handle': is
not a member of 'v8' (compiling source file ..\src\bufferutil.cc) [c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node _modules\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
  c:\users\vladi\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.18.3\include\node\v8-platform.h(16): note: see declaration of 'v8' (compiling source file ..\src\bufferutil.cc)
c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(122): error C2061: syntax error:  identifier 'Handle' (compiling source file ..\src\bufferutil.cc) [c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node _modules\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(122): error C2084: function 'boo l NanBooleanOptionValue(v8::Local<v8::Object>)' already has a body (compiling source file ..\src\bufferutil.cc) [c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node _modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
  c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(105): note: see previous defin
  ition of 'NanBooleanOptionValue' (compiling source file ..\src\bufferutil.cc)
c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(123): error C2065: 'opt': undecl ared identifier (compiling source file ..\src\bufferutil.cc) [c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modu les\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(123): error C2065: 'NanBooleanOp tionValue': undeclared identifier (compiling source file ..\src\bufferutil.cc) [c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\e ngine.io\node_modules\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(128): error C2039: 'Handle': is
not a member of 'v8' (compiling source file ..\src\bufferutil.cc) [c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node _modules\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
  c:\users\vladi\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.18.3\include\node\v8-platform.h(16): note: see declaration of 'v8' (compiling source file ..\src\bufferutil.cc)
c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(128): error C2061: syntax error:  identifier 'Handle' (compiling source file ..\src\bufferutil.cc) [c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node _modules\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(132): error C2065: 'opt': undecl ared identifier (compiling source file ..\src\bufferutil.cc) [c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modu les\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(133): error C2065: 'opt': undecl ared identifier (compiling source file ..\src\bufferutil.cc) [c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modu les\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(134): error C2065: 'opt': undecl ared identifier (compiling source file ..\src\bufferutil.cc) [c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modu les\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(135): error C2065: 'def': undecl ared identifier (compiling source file ..\src\bufferutil.cc) [c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modu les\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(213): error C2039: 'ThrowExcepti on': is not a member of 'v8' (compiling source file ..\src\bufferutil.cc) [c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine .io\node_modules\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
  c:\users\vladi\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.18.3\include\node\v8-platform.h(16): note: see declaration of 'v8' (compiling source file ..\src\bufferutil.cc)
c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(213): error C2039: 'New': is not  a member of 'v8::String' (compiling source file ..\src\bufferutil.cc) [c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io \node_modules\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
  c:\users\vladi\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.18.3\include\node\v8.h(2798): note: see declaration of 'v8::String' (compiling source file ..\src\bufferutil.cc)
c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(213): error C3861: 'New': identi fier not found (compiling source file ..\src\bufferutil.cc) [c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modul es\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(213): error C3861: 'ThrowExcepti on': identifier not found (compiling source file ..\src\bufferutil.cc) [c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io \node_modules\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(216): error C2039: 'Handle': is
not a member of 'v8' (compiling source file ..\src\bufferutil.cc) [c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node _modules\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
  c:\users\vladi\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.18.3\include\node\v8-platform.h(16): note: see declaration of 'v8' (compiling source file ..\src\bufferutil.cc)
c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(216): error C2065: 'Handle': und eclared identifier (compiling source file ..\src\bufferutil.cc) [c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_m odules\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(216): error C2275: 'v8::Value':
illegal use of this type as an expression (compiling source file ..\src\bufferutil.cc) [c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_m odules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
  c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(216): note: see declaration of
   'v8::Value' (compiling source file ..\src\bufferutil.cc)
c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(216): error C2065: 'error': unde clared identifier (compiling source file ..\src\bufferutil.cc) [c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_mo dules\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(216): error C2182: 'NanThrowErro r': illegal use of type 'void' (compiling source file ..\src\bufferutil.cc) [c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engi ne.io\node_modules\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(216): error C7525: inline variab les require at least '/std:c++17' (compiling source file ..\src\bufferutil.cc) [c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\e ngine.io\node_modules\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(216): error C2365: 'NanThrowErro r': redefinition; previous definition was 'function' (compiling source file ..\src\bufferutil.cc) [c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socke t.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
  c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(212): note: see declaration of
   'NanThrowError' (compiling source file ..\src\bufferutil.cc)
c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(216): error C2448: 'NanThrowErro r': function-style initializer appears to be a function definition (compiling source file ..\src\bufferutil.cc) [c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node _modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(222): error C2039: 'New': is not  a member of 'v8::String' (compiling source file ..\src\bufferutil.cc) [c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io \node_modules\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
  c:\users\vladi\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.18.3\include\node\v8.h(2798): note: see declaration of 'v8::String' (compiling source file ..\src\bufferutil.cc)
c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(222): error C3861: 'New': identi fier not found (compiling source file ..\src\bufferutil.cc) [c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modul es\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(224): error C2039: 'New': is not  a member of 'v8::String' (compiling source file ..\src\bufferutil.cc) [c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io \node_modules\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
  c:\users\vladi\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.18.3\include\node\v8.h(2798): note: see declaration of 'v8::String' (compiling source file ..\src\bufferutil.cc)
c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(224): error C3861: 'New': identi fier not found (compiling source file ..\src\bufferutil.cc) [c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modul es\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(224): error C2660: 'v8::Integer: :New': function does not take 1 arguments (compiling source file ..\src\bufferutil.cc) [c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_m odules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
  c:\users\vladi\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.18.3\include\node\v8.h(3294): note: see declaration of 'v8::Integer::New' (compiling source file ..\src\bufferutil.cc)
c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(225): error C2665: 'NanThrowErro r': none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types (compiling source file ..\src\bufferutil.cc) [c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_m odules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
  c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(212): note: could be 'void Nan
  ThrowError(const char *)' (compiling source file ..\src\bufferutil.cc)
  c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(225): note: while trying to ma
  tch the argument list '(v8::Local<v8::Value>)' (compiling source file ..\src\bufferutil.cc)
c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(229): error C2039: 'ThrowExcepti on': is not a member of 'v8' (compiling source file ..\src\bufferutil.cc) [c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine .io\node_modules\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
  c:\users\vladi\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.18.3\include\node\v8-platform.h(16): note: see declaration of 'v8' (compiling source file ..\src\bufferutil.cc)
c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(229): error C2039: 'New': is not  a member of 'v8::String' (compiling source file ..\src\bufferutil.cc) [c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\eliadmin-npm-test\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io \node_modules\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
```

Comment: have you tried deleting node_modules and than doing an npm install?

Comment: Yes of course. Few times.The package.json for test purpose contained only dns package.